# How to insert data in 'Person or Group' field using VS2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

Right now in my program I've made a List in SharePoint having a column **'Person or Group'**

-Allow multiple selections: **Yes**.

Now in C# I made a form and I fetch the data from People Picker.

and I am inserting that data in the **List**:

like this:

```
{
    string strName = "8;1001";    //User.Id and User.LoginName of **single** user 
    objItem["name"] = strName;
}
```

Now thats working fine. but I don't know how to insert for multiple user.

I tried it by separating with "**; (semicolon)**"
 but it gives Invalid Look-up value error.

Just Like this:

```
{
    string strName = "8;1001;2;2001";    //User.Id and User.LoginName of **2 users**
    objItem["name"] = strName;
}
```

Comment: any hint? I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add more than one user at single time in SharePoint List. Users' values may come from an Active Directory or metadata.  All the users are in a string as comma or semicolon separated value.  Let us suppose users are in below format as you are separating with '`;`'.

```
string usercontrolvalue = "dhananjay,arun,anoj,patra,mub";
```

Here is complete information about these:
[Multiple user insertion in Sharepoint list](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/multiple-user-insertion-in-sharepoint-list/)
[Using the SharePoint ‘Person or Group’ field in code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2009/02/17/quick-tip-using-the-sharepoint-person-or-group-field-in-code-part-1.aspx)

You can take idea from this and can implement your functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the detail code:-

```
void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //ctrlpplPicker is object of PeopleEditor
 string[] userarray = ctrlpplPicker.CommaSeparatedAccounts.ToString().Split(',');;
 SPFieldUserValueCollection usercollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();

 for (int i = 0; i < userarray.Length; i++)
 {
     SPFieldUserValue usertoadd = ConvertLoginAccount(userarray[i]);
     usercollection.Add(usertoadd);
 }

 SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["user tasks"];
 SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
 item["Team"] = usercollection;
 item.Update();

}
public SPFieldUserValue ConvertLoginAccount(string userid)
{
 SPFieldUserValue uservalue;
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
 {
     using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
     {
         SPUser requireduser = web.EnsureUser(userid);
         uservalue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, requireduser.ID, requireduser.LoginName);
     }
 }
 return uservalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this post - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2009/02/17/quick-tip-using-the-sharepoint-person-or-group-field-in-code-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`SPFieldUserValueCollection Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservaluecollection.aspx) to set a multi value person field:

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection value = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
value.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user1.ID, user1.Name)));
value.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user2.ID, user2.Name)));

objItem["name"] = value;
objItem.Update();
```

Where `user1` and `user2` represent `SPUser` objects.

If you just have the login names of the user accounts

**Tip:**
To update a single value person field you can just set the user ID:

```
objItem["name"] = User.ID;
```